# time between two rows in r

Tags: sql, r

I have a firewall log file that includes date, hour, src_address, dest_address.
I want to find time between two rows that src_address and dest_address is unique in r and median of these times group by src_address and dest_address in seconds.It could find in sql because I'm using sqlfd library for r as well.
Here is a part of my file;

```
             date     hour   src_address  dest_address
    2  2018-04-13 05:55:05 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
    4  2018-04-13 05:55:10 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
    6  2018-04-13 05:55:52 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
    8  2018-04-13 05:56:24 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
    10 2018-04-13 05:56:26 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
    12 2018-04-13 05:56:31 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
454   2018-04-13 15:09:52 167.99.204.115 172.16.16.153
456   2018-04-13 15:10:12 167.99.204.115 172.16.16.159
458   2018-04-13 15:10:37   140143250121 192.168.1.112
460   2018-04-13 15:11:43  176.64.141.67 172.16.16.159
462   2018-04-13 15:12:45 180.158.63.162 172.16.16.153
464   2018-04-13 15:12:49 180.158.63.162 172.16.16.153
466   2018-04-13 15:14:48   36.255.67.14   172.16.16.5
468   2018-04-13 15:15:41  220.250.26.66 192.168.1.112
470   2018-04-13 15:16:04    95.6.76.181 192.168.1.111
472   2018-04-13 15:17:35   198.12.97.85 172.16.16.159
474   2018-04-13 15:18:19  167.99.152.22 192.168.1.112
476   2018-04-13 15:20:39   96.64.199.69 172.16.16.153
478   2018-04-13 15:30:49   52.186.127.7 192.168.1.112
480   2018-04-13 15:30:53   52.186.127.7 192.168.1.112
482   2018-04-13 15:31:31   198.8.88.152  194.27.152.2
484   2018-04-13 15:40:54   198.12.97.85 192.168.1.112
486   2018-04-13 15:41:35  196.52.43.127 172.16.16.153
488   2018-04-13 15:41:42  218.17.221.58 172.16.16.153
490   2018-04-13 15:43:09    79.2.22.244   172.16.16.5
492   2018-04-13 15:49:41    81149211134 172.16.16.153
```

Here is my expected output

```
src_address  dest_address    median

37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100      5
218.17.221.58 172.16.16.153      3
52.186.127.7 192.168.1.112       150
```

Comment: In R or in sql? And don't paste your data as a picture. That is of no use to us.

Comment: Also please show us the expected output and what you have tried.

Comment: I've edited as you want.Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Input data:
head(df)
#     date     hour   src_address  dest_address
# 1 2018-04-13 05:55:05 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
# 2 2018-04-13 05:55:10 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
# 3 2018-04-13 05:55:52 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
# 4 2018-04-13 05:56:24 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
# 5 2018-04-13 05:56:26 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100
# 6 2018-04-13 05:56:31 37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100


#Look at the structure of dataset to check the types of columns:
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 24 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ date        : chr  "2018-04-13" "2018-04-13" "2018-04-13" "2018-04-13" ...
# $ hour        : chr  "05:55:05" "05:55:10" "05:55:52" "05:56:24" ...
# $ src_address : chr  "37.142.41.133" "37.142.41.133" "37.142.41.133" "37.142.41.133" ...
# $ dest_address: chr  "172.16.16.100" "172.16.16.100" "172.16.16.100" "172.16.16.100" ...


# Create a single date and time variable for convinience
# and convert it into POSIXlt format (you need to change the time zone to your own)
df$Date.Time <- as.POSIXlt(strptime( paste(df$date, df$hour), tz="EST",
                                                         format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

# sort the data to make sure all records that have the same source and destination address are
# together
df <- df[with(df, order(src_address, dest_address, Date.Time)), ]

# Calculate the difference in time between each observation
df$time.int <- c(0,df$Date.Time[-1]- df$Date.Time[-nrow(df)])

# Mark the first time interval for the group with the same source and destination as 0
df$time.int[!duplicated(paste(df$src_address, df$dest_address))] <- 0
df
# date     hour    src_address  dest_address           Date.Time time.int
# 16 2018-04-13 15:18:19  167.99.152.22 192.168.1.112 2018-04-13 15:18:19        0
# 7  2018-04-13 15:09:52 167.99.204.115 172.16.16.153 2018-04-13 15:09:52        0
# 8  2018-04-13 15:10:12 167.99.204.115 172.16.16.159 2018-04-13 15:10:12        0
# 9  2018-04-13 15:11:43  176.64.141.67 172.16.16.159 2018-04-13 15:11:43        0
# 10 2018-04-13 15:12:45 180.158.63.162 172.16.16.153 2018-04-13 15:12:45        0
# 11 2018-04-13 15:12:49 180.158.63.162 172.16.16.153 2018-04-13 15:12:49        4
# 22 2018-04-13 15:41:35  196.52.43.127 172.16.16.153 2018-04-13 15:41:35        0
# 15 2018-04-13 15:17:35   198.12.97.85 172.16.16.159 2018-04-13 15:17:35        0
# 21 2018-04-13 15:40:54   198.12.97.85 192.168.1.112 2018-04-13 15:40:54        0
# 20 2018-04-13 15:31:31   198.8.88.152  194.27.152.2 2018-04-13 15:31:31        0
# 23 2018-04-13 15:41:42  218.17.221.58 172.16.16.153 2018-04-13 15:41:42        0
# 13 2018-04-13 15:15:41  220.250.26.66 192.168.1.112 2018-04-13 15:15:41        0
# 12 2018-04-13 15:14:48   36.255.67.14   172.16.16.5 2018-04-13 15:14:48        0
# 1  2018-04-13 05:55:05  37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100 2018-04-13 05:55:05        0
# 2  2018-04-13 05:55:10  37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100 2018-04-13 05:55:10        5
# 3  2018-04-13 05:55:52  37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100 2018-04-13 05:55:52       42
# 4  2018-04-13 05:56:24  37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100 2018-04-13 05:56:24       32
# 5  2018-04-13 05:56:26  37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100 2018-04-13 05:56:26        2
# 6  2018-04-13 05:56:31  37.142.41.133 172.16.16.100 2018-04-13 05:56:31        5
# 18 2018-04-13 15:30:49   52.186.127.7 192.168.1.112 2018-04-13 15:30:49        0
# 19 2018-04-13 15:30:53   52.186.127.7 192.168.1.112 2018-04-13 15:30:53        4
# 24 2018-04-13 15:43:09    79.2.22.244   172.16.16.5 2018-04-13 15:43:09        0
# 14 2018-04-13 15:16:04    95.6.76.181 192.168.1.111 2018-04-13 15:16:04        0
# 17 2018-04-13 15:20:39   96.64.199.69 172.16.16.153 2018-04-13 15:20:39        0




# define the function that will calculate the mean:
# If only one unique value - return NA
# If there are more than one value - omit the first one
my.mean <- function(x){ if (length(x) < 2 ) return(NA) else return(median(x[-1])) }


# Use dplyr package to aggregate and summarize time.intcolumn using src_address and dest_address columns
library(dplyr)
df[,c(3,4,6)] %>% group_by (src_address, dest_address) %>% summarise(med_int = my.mean(time.int))

# Output:
# # A tibble: 17 x 3
# # Groups:   src_address [?]
#      src_address    dest_address  med_int
#      <fct>          <fct>           <dbl>
#  1 167.99.152.22  192.168.1.112      NA
#  2 167.99.204.115 172.16.16.153      NA
#  3 167.99.204.115 172.16.16.159      NA
#  4 176.64.141.67  172.16.16.159      NA
#  5 180.158.63.162 172.16.16.153       4
#  6 196.52.43.127  172.16.16.153      NA
#  7 198.12.97.85   172.16.16.159      NA
#  8 198.12.97.85   192.168.1.112      NA
#  9 198.8.88.152   194.27.152.2       NA
# 10 218.17.221.58  172.16.16.153      NA
# 11 220.250.26.66  192.168.1.112      NA
# 12 36.255.67.14   172.16.16.5        NA
# 13 37.142.41.133  172.16.16.100       5
# 14 52.186.127.7   192.168.1.112       4
# 15 79.2.22.244    172.16.16.5        NA
# 16 95.6.76.181    192.168.1.111      NA
# 17 96.64.199.69   172.16.16.153      NA
#
```

Comment: When I tried the df$Date.Time <- as.POSIXlt( paste(df$date, df$hour)) this I get an error like Error in as.POSIXlt.character(paste(real_data$date, real_data$hour)) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.   What should I do?Thanks

Comment: I added str() output to my answer. Check the the column types are characters and convert if needed.

Comment: output of str(df) of both (you and me ) are same but I get same error

Comment: Can you try df$Date.Time <- strptime( paste(df$date[1], df$hour[1]), tz="EST",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
 and see if it works. You need to put your own time zone

Comment: It works.But now time.int column are 0  all.there is no another number .It should be because there is a time difference

Comment: Sorry you need to remove [1] in my answer in comment. I used it for testing. Try: df$Date.Time <- as.POSIXlt(strptime( paste(df$date, df$hour), tz="EST",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

Comment: Thank you very much.This is incredible.

Comment: Please "accept" the answer if the solution works for you. It will help others to see that this solution is working. Thank you.

Comment: Katia I have another question How can I get the number of unique(src_address and dest_address) per hour and per min?Could you help me?Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly (for each pair of src_address and dest_address??). If so: tapply(paste(df$src_address,df$dest_address),
       as.character(df$Date.Time), FUN=function(x){length(unique(x))}). For the sample I have all of them are equal to 1. If you mean something else, let me know.

Comment: Do you need to use date? Or just hour and minute without seconds? Also Do you want separate src_address and separate dest_address or for each unique pair of src_address and dest_address?

Comment: I mean something like this; we will find number of appearence each pair of src_address and dest_address per min and per hour.Then it will find max appearence per min and per hour for unique addresses (src_address and dest_address)?                                                               So  src_address    dest_address     max_per_min    max_per_hour              1     37.142.41.133   192.168.1.112             5                       25              1     32.220.41.133   192.113.1.2                 3                       15                 like this

Comment: Both date and hour,minute surely. not seperate for each pair

Comment: If you do not need seconds, then: tapply(substring(df$Date.Time, 1,16), paste(df$src_address, df$dest_address), length)

Comment: Your last comment calculate count of the each pair.But I mean that we will find  every minute count for each pair and then we will find max number for per minutes.And we will find  every hour count for each pair and then we will find max number for per hour